# Create 6 band IMG file with GDAL out of two JPG files, one with WorldFile coordinates

Tags: raster, gdal, georeferencing

I have two JPG files

## 1 ortomap: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/ortofoto1.jpg/

with WorldFile:

```
0.683772574816354
0.000000000000000
0.000000000000000
-0.683739485024190
395057.114562241190000
741149.458682749890000
```

## 2 aerial photo in form of JPG: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/688/aerialphoto.jpg/

**How can I create a 6 band IMG out of those two JPGs but according to the coordinates from the first JPG WorldFile using GDAL?**

I am after some exemplary commadline commads

Comment: The second image needs some georeferencing information as well, unless you are assuming both images cover the same extent.  Is that correct?